# How do I get my factorial generator to work? I believe my algorithm is wrong

Tags: javascript, generator

I am trying to make a generator using factorials, however my outputs are never exactly what I'm looking for.

I've tried a plethora of different things, however I am no able to decrease to the next number even with a for loop.

```js
function getFactorialGenerator() {
  var a = 5;
  var b = a - 1;

  return function() {
    a *= b;
    return a;
  }
}

var next = getFactorialGenerator();

console.log(next());
console.log(next());
```

I expected the first output to print "20" and then the second output to print 60. 
The outputs both print 2.

Comment: Works just fine…!?

Comment: Hi, sorry about your question being closed. I guess you're looking for `a *= b--` in your generator function. This way you correctly get 20 - 60 - 120. The only problem is that you have to intercept 0 in the calling code to stop the generator on time.